# Errors when AWS Lambda function is triggered by Kinesis

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a very simple AWS Lambda function that is written in Java and is triggered by a Kinesis stream. Whenever it runs, I get the following error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting
>   setter definitions for property "encryptionType":
>   com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.Record#setEncryptionType(1
>   params) vs
>   com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.Record#setEncryptionType(1
>   params)

This is the code:

```
package com.domo.kinesis;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.KinesisEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.KinesisEvent.KinesisEventRecord;

public class TriggeredLambdaFunction {

    private LambdaLogger logger;

    public int handleRequest(KinesisEvent event, Context context) {
        logger = context.getLogger();

        for (KinesisEventRecord eventRecord : event.getRecords()) {
            String partitionKey = eventRecord.getKinesis().getPartitionKey();
            String sequenceNumber = eventRecord.getKinesis().getSequenceNumber();
            String data = new String(eventRecord.getKinesis().getData().array());
            logger.log(String.format("Partition: %s\nSequence: %s\nData: %s\n", partitionKey, sequenceNumber, data));
        }

        return event.getRecords().size();
    }
}
```

The Record class does have 2 different setEncryptionType() methods, but this library comes from Amazon and I can't change it.

What do I need to do to get my function to run correctly?